# Codeship.io and Bluehost(or other shared hosting environment)

Tags: deployment, continuous-deployment

I've been confused on how to set up codeship.io with Bluehost, and wanted to know if there was any good documentation I should be looking over? I already looked at CodeShip's docs, and they weren't very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the founders of Codeship.

How are you currently deploying into Bluehost? Do you have ssh access or only ftp?

You can also either send me an email to flo@codeship.io or send us a support message through our in-app support.

Comment: I have ssh access, but usually only use FTP.

Comment: The easiest way to deploy in there would be through SSH, or SFTP. Take a look at our docs to see if that's an option for you:

https://codeship.io/documentation/continuous-deployment/deployment-with-ftp-sftp-scp/

Comment: Okay, so after I add the ssh public key to my server I just put the command line commands to move files into the script deployment tab?

Comment: Exactly just adding it into the script deployment for the branch you want to deploy

Comment: Alright, just double checking. I add the ssh key to my server, and the script development tab. Then after that I cd into the directory I want. Should I have the git repo on my server?

Comment: You don't necessarily need it in your server. You can just clone it during deployment for example.